# AS3 How to keep text box in one frame

Tags: actionscript-3, textbox

I'm trying to add a few text boxes so that people can select text and copy it to their clipboard.

I wrote the following, but the problem is that the text box stays through all the frames after it's been accessed and I just want it to stay in that frame. Do I have to set them on invisible elsewhere? How come other frames even have access to this code?

Any solutions? Thanks!

```
stop();

var myFont = new fontCandy();

var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat.size = 10;
myFormat.font = myFont.fontName;
myFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;

var myText:TextField = new TextField();
myText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
myText.embedFonts = true;
myText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
myText.text = "my@email.com";

addChild(myText);

myText.border = true;
myText.wordWrap = true;
myText.width = 100;
myText.height = 15;
myText.x = 70;
myText.y = 185;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FlashPro, anything done in code is not subject to timeline keyframes.  Something done in code will persist until it's scope (the timeline it's on) is unloaded or you've explicitly cleaned it up via code. (though certain things can keep your objects in memory even after this).

This also includes display objects that originated on the timeline (not through code) but have had their parentage or positioning manipulated via code (so if you use addChild/setChildIndex on a timeline object)

You have to explicitly remove it by using `removeChild(instanceOrVarName);`

So in your case: `removeChild(myText);` will remove that text field.

So, to sum it up:

> Things done through code must be cleaned up through code.

Here are a few options for you to explore:

- call `removeChild(myText)` on the very next frame
- listen for the `ENTER_FRAME` event and check if the playhead has moved, if so then do `removeChild(myText)` and remove the listener.
- on the frame you have this code, put a text field on the stage (just on that frame), give it an instance name of `myText`, then keep the code you have except for the `new TextField()` line, and the `addChild` line.  This should make it do what you want but also let it be removed on the next frame.

Comment: I chose to use the last option, as I have multiple buttons on the page and I don't want to put a code on all the frames it refers to, or even on all frames; I'd rather handle it on the frame itself.

I don't know much about the parent/child coding, but I can see where it might be useful to do it like that. For now I'm going to stick to your third way though.

Although the dynamic text didn't let me select itself in flash, I chose input text and it works well. - Sorry for the noobishness!